# Leer json en arduino enviado por puerto serial desde php

Tags: arduino

Amigos tengo un problema con el arduino al recibir la información. Desde php genero un json y se lo mando por puerto serial eso funciona, pero a la hora de recibir el json me quedo corto mostrándome algo incoherente el arduino Ejemplo:`!sj/8ssl` y lo que le debería llegar seria:

```
{"nombre":"Arroz Diana","manejo":"s","descripcion":"Libra de arroz de 500gr","precio":"5690","barcode":"32412412412"}.
```

Código:

```
void loop() {

if (Serial.available()>0) {    

//Aquí esta el problema donde lo recibe

          String serialRead = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
          char charBuf[serialRead.length() + 1];
          serialRead.toCharArray(charBuf, serialRead.length());

//esto es para mostrar cosas mas adelante
          DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
          deserializeJson(doc, serialRead);
          JsonObject object = doc.to<JsonObject>();
//Aquí termina el problema


 }
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el json que él envió?

Comment: `... se lo mando por puerto serial eso funciona ...` ¿ Como sabes que funciona si te está llegando información incorrecta ?

Comment: @Trauma Si le envía al puerto seria correctamente utilice varias app externas para mirar que el llega al puerto si le llega pero en el arduino no se que pasa no si tengo que leer el json como un array o como un objeto.

Comment: Vale. Descartado eso ... ¿ Como lo estás mostrando ? Porque el código no llega ahí.

Comment: suena a fallo de configuracion del objeto Serial... no tienes un objeto serial (en lugar de la clase Serial)? donde lo defines?

Comment: @Trauma yo después lo muestro con una librería propia de lcd que uso lo pongo a que me liste la variable que recibiría el puerto serial pero solo aparecen cosas que ni se sabe donde salio eso

Comment: @Jakala void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
 //solo tengo esto tengo que especificar algo más?
 
   
}

Comment: ¿ Has verificado que `object.isNull( ) == false`, para descartar errores de memoria y/o *parseo* ?

Comment: Tiene todo el aspecto de que la velocidad del puerto serial en Arduino es distinta a la que usa el PC.